# How to have MS-Access Query Builder return results from multiple "Not Equals" Criteria?

Tags: microsoft-access

The problem is when you want to use MS Access's Query Builder to perform a search based on multiple 'not equals' values.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you want to use MS Access's Query Builder to perform a search based on multiple 'not equals' values.  The solution makes sense, but it seems counter intuitive.  Also, I know that writing it in SQL can be easier, but this works and it's great for beginners.

Here is the solution.
In the "Criteria" for the value you want to search, you need to put in the "not equal" sign "<>" then your first value, (in quotes if it is text), then you must use "And" to join more not equal values.  While it seems that you would use an "Or", you must use "And."

So a Criteria will look like this...
    <>"Texas" And <>"Ohio" And <>"Washington"

This will return all other values besides these three states.

Again, there might be other ways of doing this, but I just wanted to share this as it seems I need to do it every few years and I can't find the solution online.

Comment: Go ahead and select this as the correct answer. I worked perfectly for my database.